# Refer office icons programatically

Tags: 2013, list, file-icons

In my SharePoint list i have column called `DocType` which has values `Docx,XLsx,PPT,Link`

If you choose any of those I wish to display the Office icons accordingly. As I know these icons are located here `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\IMAGES`

I dont see any way how I can Access it through url? One way could be to put all those needed images in my Project inside layouts folder and show from there.

Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The icon URL is:

```
http://your-sharepoint-url/_layouts/15/images/
```

For example:

```
http://your-sharepoint-url/_layouts/15/images/icdocx.png
```

Comment: thats wrong.. have you tried yourself?

Comment: @Happy Of course I tried and can see the icons.

Comment: Threre is no images folder on this path C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/purtuga/SPImages

has an .ASPX page you drop into a Library which lets you browse all the SharePoint default images

Comment: how it use it programatically ?

Answer (score 0):

As you're asking about retrieving the icon url **programmatically**.

In case you use **client side** programming technique, you can use:

- JavaScript: `SP.Web.mapToIcon()`([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/office/jj245123.aspx))
- C#: `Web.MapToIcon()`([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.maptoicon.aspx))

For **server side** programming you can use the static method `SPUtility.MapToIcon()`([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/office/ms468490.aspx)).

Example in JavaScript for client side programming:

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();

// the following returns sth. like "icdocx.png"
var iconName = web.mapToIcon('path to document', '', SP.Utilities.IconSize.Size16);

// Perform executeQueryAsync on ctx ...

// OnSucceed you can build the URL for the icon like this:
var imgSrc = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/" + _spPageContextInfo.layoutsUrl + "/images/" + iconName;
```